# Bootstrap navbar-fixed-top not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap's `navbar-top-fixed` on my site but it doesn't seem to work. When I scroll down, it isn't fixed at the top.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="gdgt-menu">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="gdgt-logo">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>" rel="bookmark">brand</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="nav-items collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <!--my menu is here-->
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.gdgt-menu{
  padding-right: 10%;
  padding-left: 10%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 200px) and (max-width : 768px) {

  .navbar{
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
  }

  .navbar-collapse {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .menu-header-container{
    width: 100%;
  }

  .gdgt-menu{
    padding-right: 0% !important;
    padding-left: 0% !important;
  }

  #bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 .current-menu-item a {
  padding-right: 100% !important;
}



}

@media only screen and (min-width : 200px) and (max-width : 768px) {

  .featured-content{
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 0px !important;
    margin-left: 0px !important;
  }


}
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 1010px) {

  .gdgt-menu{
    padding-right: 0% !important;
    padding-left: 0% !important;
  }

  .nav-items{
    width: 85% !important;
  }

}


.nav-items{
    width: 70%;
    float: right;
}


.navbar{
    height: 60px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.menu{
  margin: 0px !important;

  padding-left: 0px !important;
}

.menu-header-container{
  float: right;
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 200px) and (max-width : 768px) {

  .menu-header-container{
    background-color: #2c3e50;
  }

  .menu li{
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
.menu li{
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 60px;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.menu li:hover{
  background-color: #34495e;
}

.menu a{
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Any idea of what is causing this problem? I am not really sure why this is happening.   However, I feel like the `@media` is causing this.

Please help :)

Comment: Probably because you are setting `.navbar { position: relative; }` in your CSS

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are overriding bootstraps default positioning of the `.fixed-top-navbar`.

From bootsrap.css

```
.navbar-fixed-top,
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
  position: fixed; /* <-- Look here */
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
}
```

From your code:

```
.navbar{
    height: 60px;
    display: block;
    position: relative; /* <-- Oh dear */
}
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Bootstrap 4+

The correct class should be: `fixed-top` rather than "nav-fixed-top". It's subtle but it makes a world of difference!

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">    
    <--etc -->
</nav>
```

I believe with bootstrap 4 you'll also have to manually add some padding otherwise the nav bar might overlap with some content.  Pls check the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code:

```css
.navbar {
    height: 60px;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
}
```